# Open RTF file and view source

Tags: asp.net, ms-word, rtf

I am building a web application that requires a number of dynamically generated RTF files to be generated, these files are currently .RTF files but I need to build them all within my application in RTF format, does anyone know a program or something that I can open them in and view the raw RTF code that creates the file eg.

```
{\rtf\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\froman Tms Rmn;}{\f1\fdecor 
Symbol;}{\f2\fswiss Helv;}}{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;
\red0\green0\blue255;\red0\green255\blue255;\red0\green255\
blue0;\red255\green0\blue255;\red255\green0\blue0;\red255\
green255\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;}{\stylesheet{\fs20 
\snext0Normal;}}{\info{\author John Doe}
{\creatim\yr1990\mo7\dy30\hr10\min48}{\version1}{\edmins0}
{\nofpages1}{\nofwords0}{\nofchars0}{\vern8351}}\widoctrl\ftnbj \sectd\linex0\endnhere \pard\plain \fs20 This is plain text.\par}
```

Thanks for any help.
J.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad, or any text editor will do. As you are creating the files yourself programatically, you will want to be liberal with carriage returns and line feeds to make the files more readable.